# WCF Data Services error "The given name 'Foo' was not found in the entity sets"

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I'm developing a WCF Data Service to expose a database. I want to provide access to one of the tables (call it 'Foo'), so I put this in the `InitializeService` method of my `DatabaseService.svc.cs`:

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Foo", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
```

However, when the service is initialized it throws an `ArgumentException` with the message "The given name 'Foo' was not found in the entity sets."

The table is definitely in the .edmx file with that name, case and spelling correct. It's also in the `.Designer.cs` file, like this:

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="FooDBModel", Name="Foo")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class Foo : EntityObject
```

The service class itself is declared as:

```
public class FooDatabaseService : DataService<FooDBEntities>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using the fully qualified name?

Comment: Yes, I've tried the combinations `FooDB.Foo`, `FooDB.dbo.Foo`, `FooDBModel.Foo`, and `FooDBEntities.Foo`.

Comment: Are any of those the actual namespace used in code (as opposed to the NamespaceName="").  Also, is your model and your service all in the same project?

Comment: Yes, those are the namespaces in the code. The .svc and .edmx are both in the same project (a dll), and it's being hosted with `DataServiceHost` in a separate Windows Service project.

Comment: Figured it out, it worked with `Foos`. Entity Framework does pluralization--doh! I'm going to give you the point, though, because the solution was to use the right name.